# VTC -> Off Topic -> Another Stack Exchange missing destinations

Tags: support

When going through the Vote to close queue, I came across a Question that more properly belongs on a different stack exchange.

Going through the flag menus (VTC -> Off Topic -> Another stack exchange) ended up with a "Migrate to" choice that contained only PoliticsMeta.

Is this a configuration issue with the Stack Exchange or a issue with my user profile or something else?